# Why isn't the non-differentiablity of a path at some finite number of points $a_1<\cdots<a_m$ points a problem when calculating the contour integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

My question is quite elementary, but I can't for the life of me remember/find the appropriate result addressing it. Suppose that $\gamma(t), a \leq t \leq b$ is a continuously differentiable path on $(a, b)$, except for some finite number of points $a_1 < \cdots < a_m$ in $[a, b]$, and $f$ is a continuous complex function on this path. Then why do we avoid the non-differentiability of $\gamma$ by calculating the contour integral of $f$ over $\gamma$ by $\sum_{i=1}^m\int_{a_i}^{a_{i+1}}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt = \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$?

Comment: As Mason said, you can take that expression as the definition of the integral. It is a well-defined number, so it makes sense. This relies on the fact that you can integrate a function that is not defined on a set of measure zero, which definitely includes finite sets. You should though check that this is independent of where you put the partitions. The latter is easy from additivity of integral over its domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like, you can define $\gamma'(t)$ arbitrarily at the points where it is discontinuous and write $\int_{\gamma}f\,dz = \int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt$. The value is the same regardless of how you choose to define $\gamma'(t)$ at the exceptional points, and moreover it equals that summation you wrote. This is because a single point has Lebesgue measure 0. It is more transparent to just define it as the summation.